# MiniUPnP interface and NAT-PMP is not going through wireguard

Tags: port-forwarding, vps, wireguard

Running a wireguard VPN on both an ubuntu VPS and Arch local machine.

Forwarded port `23288` on VPS's wireguard conf with iptable rule:

```
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d vps.public.ip -p tcp --dport 23288 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.66.66.2
```

In which `10.66.66.2` is my local's machine's wireguard internal address.

But then the stuff going through the `23288/tcp` is using NAT-PMP or MiniUPnP, and the stuff are not going through.

What do I need to add to the iptables rule in order to allow those packets using either one of the two protocol is go through?

EDIT: Please let me know if what I think here is incorrect too.

Program used here that utilizes the port and protocol is called airdcpp-webclient on Arch local.

Comment: those protocols are using SSDP multicast. A router isn't a multicast router. It might not be as simple as adding an iptables rule. I guess one has to understand how NAT-PMP and UPnP work, and maybe run a multicast server like smcroute.

Comment: @A.B, I don't think I need to set up things like smcroute, since the program I use, airdc is verified to be able to tunnel and connect with wireguard but just that it needs some adjustments. I believe it is just missing something somewhere if not iptables rules.

Comment: @A.B Pardon my dumbness, I did read through more things, and I think you are right, in I need to set up a multi cast service, but can you link me to a way of how I would go about doing that?
I have no idea how to setup a multi cast service on a server.

Comment: It's not a flow from outside to inside. It's a flow from the inside client to the upnp server running on the outside vpn server doing nat. That means you do need a nat-pmp and/or upnp server installed too there and understand how it's working. You must of course change your question accordingly. I never used such upnp server. But with a good description of the problem somebody might answer.

Comment: You'd better have it working once without the tunnel anyway to know where's the non-working part (I hope you're not behind CGNAT...).

Comment: @A.B, if I just let the app use my home connection everything is perfect except the fact that my ip is exposed, so the problem is indeed only smth that happens after I start vpn-ing.

Comment: @A.B It is true, I just tested the app without forwarding the ports from router to local ip on a home connection without vpn, and it works alright since the router has UPnP enabled. But not NAT-PMP mode. So how should I phrase my question? Would smth like this work? "How do I set up a Upnp server on vps for my local machine to connect to via vpn?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125040/discussion-between-asmodean-and-a-b).